Can we assume final states in DPDAs have no $\epsilon$-transitions?
I'm struggling with a conceptual issue related to deterministic pushdown automata (DPDAs) as described in the book Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation (3rd ed.) by Hopcroft, Ullman, and Motwani. The book defines a DPDA as follows:

A PDA $ P = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, Z_0, F) $ is deterministic if and only if the following conditions are met:

$ \delta(q, a, X) $ has at most one member for any $ q \in Q $, $ a \in \Sigma $ or $ a = \epsilon $, and $ X \in \Gamma $.
If $ \delta(q, a, X) $ is nonempty for some $ a \in \Sigma $, then $ \delta(q, \epsilon, X) $ must be empty.


In the proof of Theorem 6.21, the authors describe how to convert a DPDA $ P = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, Z_0, F) $ that accepts a language $L$ by final state into another DPDA $ P'$ that accepts $L\\\$ = \{w\\\$ \mid w \in L\}$ by emptying its stack. The construction proceeds as follows:

Add a new state $q$ that $P'$ enters whenever $P$ is in an accepting state and the next input is $\\\$$. In state $q$, $P'$ pops all symbols off its stack. Also, $P'$ needs its own bottom-of-stack marker to avoid accidentally emptying its stack while simulating $P$.

Here’s the problem I see: if $\delta(q_f, \epsilon, X)$ is nonempty for some $q_f \in F$, then adding the transition $\delta(q_f, \\\$, X) = \{(q, X)\}$ in the construction would violate the second condition for determinism because $q_f$ would now have both $\epsilon$-transitions and valid transitions on $\\\$$, making $P'$ non-deterministic.
A similar issue arises in Introduction to Languages and the Theory of Computation (4th ed.) by John C. Martin in exercise 5.20 and its solution.
This makes me wonder:

Are we allowed to assume, without loss of generality, that final states in DPDAs have no $\epsilon$-transitions?
If not, how can the construction of $P'$ still result in a deterministic PDA?

What am I missing in this reasoning? Any clarification would be appreciated.

Simultaneously cross-posted to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/54943/can-we-assume-final-states-in-dpdas-have-no-epsilon-transitions .

Yes, one may assume that a DPDA has not $\varepsilon$-states in its accepting states. But this fact is not mentioned in the HU&M text, unless I overlooked some remark.
A DPDA might digress in long $\varepsilon$-computations, so in accepting a string it is sometimes necessary to continue a little after the last letter has been read before reaching the accepting state. Once we are in the accepting state the $\varepsilon$-transitions are no longer interesting except for reaching the next input symbol.
Here is what we can do. In an accepting state $q$ (and top of stack $X$) with $\varepsilon$-transitions we `predict' the next input symbol: for each $a$ we read $a$ and move to state $(q,a)$. Then we continue simulating the original DPDA following $\varepsilon$-transitions, all the time remembering we still have to follow an $a$-transition in the original automaton. Once we find such an $a$-transition we follow that using an $\varepsilon$-transition back to the original automaton. All other symbols are ignored during this simulation.

Thank you for your answer; it is immensely valuable to me. However, I couldn’t fully understand how you constructed a new DPDA without $\epsilon$-transitions on accepting states that recognizes the same language. Could you please specify the new DPDA in detail, including its states and transitions, in a rigorous manner?
